# Browser limited 400 error when logging in

Tags: error-message, admin, login

At random times local sites don't allow me to login to admin with certain browsers. Currently I cannot login to a site using Chrome, but can using Firefox. I have had sites that won't login with Firefox, but do with Chrome.

The error is a browser console error, not a Craft/Twig error:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

I've renamed and deleted cpresources (as another post had mentioned to try), but this didn't work.

It happens at random points too. I can login fine then come away from my PC for a few minutes to return to a login screen and not able to login.

Comment: What are you using to localhost your site?

Comment: @CraftQuest - currently using MAMP for Windows. A colleague of mine has had a similar issue on their Mac, also using MAMP. One site in particular (that is live) also gives the same issue, that's running on a Linux based server